# matplotlib: if I set fig height, x legend is cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to set the figure size with `fig1.set_size_inches(5.5,3)` on python, but the plot produces a fig where the x label is not completely visibile. The figure itself has the size I need, but it seems like the axis inside is too tall, and the x label just doesn't fit anymore.

here is my code:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1.set_size_inches(5.5,4)
fig1.set_dpi(300)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True,which='both')
ax.hist(driveDistance,100)
ax.set_xlabel('Driven Distance in km')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
fig1.savefig('figure1_distance.png')
```

and here is the result file:

[image: image with 5.5x3 inch]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could order the save method to take the artist of the x-label into consideration.

This is done with the bbox_extra_artists and the tight layout. 
The resulting code would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1.set_size_inches(5.5,4)
fig1.set_dpi(300)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True,which='both')
ax.hist(driveDistance,100)
xlabel = ax.set_xlabel('Driven Distance in km')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
fig1.savefig('figure1_distance.png', bbox_extra_artists=[xlabel], bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: with subplots you can also use `fig1.tight_layout()` instead of `bbox_inches='tight'`

Comment: only specifying bbox_inches='tight' works for my label-cut-off issue, thanks!

Comment: Actually, the variable `xlabel` might not be needed. Only changing the last line of code to `fig1.savefig('figure1_distance.png', bbox_inches='tight')` will do the work

Comment: fig.tight_layout() worked for me if I place it at the end, that is, after I have define all my axis labels for example.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me if I initialize the figure with the `figsize` and `dpi` as `kwargs`:

```
from numpy import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
driveDistance = random.exponential(size=100)
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,4),dpi=300)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True,which='both')
ax.hist(driveDistance,100)
ax.set_xlabel('Driven Distance in km')
ax.set_ylabel('Frequency')
fig1.savefig('figure1_distance.png')
```

[image: driveDistance]

Comment: it didn't work for me... same result as before. The answer from @Tal did work perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Might be a backend issue, I'm using `MacOSX`.  Anyway, at least you know you can select figure size and dpi from the start :)

Comment: of course, I adopted this part of the code as well. I'm running mac os x as well, python 2.7.3.